# Make request to Lambda Function URL with access token as Authorization header

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito, access-token

I've been dealing with this for a while. I want to call an AWS_IAM authenticated Lambda Function URL sending an access token (generated by Cognito User pool) as the Authorization header.

I know I can send access token as a request header for API Gateway HTTP or REST API, but I'm not sure if it works for Lambda Functions too.

I couldn't find any documentation about my problem, just this other about Signature V4 authentication method to invoke Lambda Functions URL: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-invocation.html

Comment: Its a little unclear what you are trying to do.  Does this not work for you?  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

The [Security and auth model for Lambda function URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/urls-auth.html) has two AuthType options:

- **AWS_IAM** – Lambda uses AWS IAM  to authenticate and authorize requests based on the IAM principal's identity policy and the function's resource-based policy.
- **NONE** – Lambda doesn't perform any authentication before invoking your function.

The Cognito JWT-based access token is not an AWS IAM session token, so cannot sign the request using SigV4.  You have a different option for each of the Lambda function URL AuthType options.

1. To use **AWS_IAM**, you can use Amazon Cognito identity pools to [deliver temporary, limited-privilege credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html) which can SigV4 sign the request.
2. To use **NONE**, you will need to [verify the JSON web token](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html) yourself, preferably with a software framework (such as [AWS JWT Verify](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-jwt-verify)).

Answer (score 0):

If the auth type is **AWS_IAM** and you're making the request using python's `requests` module then this should work for you. I'm using [aws-requests-auth](https://pypi.org/project/aws-requests-auth/) to sign the request.

*Note about credentials*: You need to provide an `aws_access_key`, an `aws_secret_access_key` and an `aws_token`. In your case (and mine), this information will need to be passed into the lambda function somehow. The preferred method is to use `Secrets`, but depending on your situation, this may or may not be workable. In the example below, I simply retrieve the credentials from the environment using `boto3.Session().get_credentials()` which in the case of `lambda` will retrieve the credentials of the function's execution role.

```py
import requests
import boto3
import urllib.parse
from aws_requests_auth.aws_auth import AWSRequestsAuth

FUNC_URL = https://EXAMPLE.lambda-url.EXAMPLE-REGION.on.aws/

credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()

auth = AWSRequestsAuth(
    aws_access_key=credentials.access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=credentials.secret_key,
    aws_token=credentials.token,
    aws_host=urllib.parse.urlparse(FUNC_URL).netloc,
    aws_region=credentials.region,
    aws_service="lambda"
)

requests.post(
    url=FUNC_URL,
    auth=auth,
    data=json.dumps({"YOUR": "DATA"}),
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}
)
```